# ¿Cómo obtener un directorio seleccionado desde el explorador de archivos como si fuera un archivo?

Tags: html

¿Es posible desde html seleccionar un directorio (carpeta) como si seleccionara un archivo normal?, es practicamente un `input file` pero en vez de esto que sea un `input directory` por ejemplo.

**Edición**
Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
<input id="directory" type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
<script>
 var folder = document.getElementById("directory");
 folder.onchange=function(){
  var files = folder.files,
  len = files.length;
  for(i=0;i<len;i+=1)
  {
   console.log(files[i]);
  }
 }
</script>
```

Y obtengo esto en la consola:

```
lastModified: 1470418232860
lastModifiedDate: Fri Aug 05 2016 12:30:32 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {}
name:"Foto carné.jpg"
size:105186
type:"image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath:"Pictures/Foto carné.jpg"
```

En realidad lo que quiero obtener es la ruta completa donde se encuentran los archivos, por ejemplo `C:User/Pictures/Foto carné.jpg` para luego poder obtener todos los archivos que tengo dentro de este directorio pero según he visto, esto no es posible por temas de seguridad. ¿Qué otra solución puedo tener para esto, teniendo en cuenta que inicialmente debo seleccionar la carpeta y no los archivos dentro de esta

Comment: tienes que ser mas claro a la hora de preguntar, hay preguntas que me hago en base a lo que expones, por ejemplo :¿Quieres obtener la url del archivo o solo quieres tomar una carpeta para subirla?. Aclara esas cosas y muestra que llevas hasta el momento , así tu pregunta será bien recibida por la comunidad. Saludos!

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas tiene que ver con webkitdirectory. Por favor revisa el siguiente link asociado [webkitdirectory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory)

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta. Creo que así dejo más claro que es lo que necesito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías solucionarlo con la propiedad "webkitdirectory". Un ejemplo asociado a como se utiliza es el siguiente:

```js
document.getElementById("filepicker").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  let output = document.getElementById("listing");
  let files = event.target.files;

  for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
    output.appendChild(item);
  };
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory multiple />
<ul id="listing"></ul>
```

Webkitdirectory es una propiedad que utilizas dentro de un **input file** para justamente poder seleccionar un directorio. Para listar los elementos se utiliza javascript como bien puedes observar en el snippet que coloqué anteriormente.

Para más información de como trabaja puedes visitar: [Webkitdirectory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) que es la fuente de donde extraje el ejemplo para mi respuesta, no modifiqué nada ya que no hubo necesidad porque hace justo lo que pides.

Espero sea de utilidad. Un saludo

Comment: Si, exactamente esto, pero quisiera obtener la ruta completa de estos archivos, aunque según he leído no es posible por temas de seguridad.

Comment: @SantiagoMuñoz Te sugiero que los archivos del sitio no posean espacios en blanco y en lo posible tampoco acentos. Por ejemplo el que mencionas como "Foto Carné" sería bueno que sea guardado como foto_carnet por ejemplo. Esto para mantener la cualidad de multiplataforma del sitio (Recuerda que windows no es estricto con muchas cosas como los espacios en blanco en las rutas pero linux si lo es)

Comment: Entiendo, la única que veo entonces es cargar directamente a mi servidor en una carpeta temporal, los archivos de la carpeta seleccionada. Y gracias por la sugerencia, la tendré en cuenta para evitarme problemas a futuro.

Comment: Si utilizas algún framework en backend se me ocurre un buen "workaround" que podrías utilizar pero depende de si utilizas un framework en backend o no, es decir, si utilizas un framework tengo garantía de que funcione porque la estructura de archivos es genérica pero si no utilizas framework si es dificil generar el workaround que tengo en mente

Comment: Si, si utilizo un framework, trabajo con laravel 5.1

Comment: Disculpa pero ya intenté el workaround que tenia pensado y no es viable por lo mismo del tema de seguridad ya que podría aplicarse pero sólo cuando el usuario selecciona archivos desde el servidor a su pc y no al revés

Comment: Vale, no hay problema, de igual modo ¡muchas gracias!.

Comment: @SantiagoMuñoz De nada. Que tengas un excelente día!

Answer (score 1):

No sé si realmente es lo que quieres hacer (no tengo rep suficiente para poner comentarios), pero se pueden elegir múltiples archivos con el input file con el atributo "multiple".

```
<input type="file" name="defaultname" size="40"  multiple>
```

Comment: Si no sabes bien lo que quiere, espera a que aclare la pregunta. Hasta que ganes el privilegio de cometnar. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

No es posible saber la ruta, a menos que uses internet explorer. Sin embargo para manejar el archivo puedes usar Base64:

```
var avatar_name = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e){
       $img_avatar.data({"avatarB64":e.target.result,"avatarNombre":avatar_name});
       $img_avatar.attr({src:e.target.result,title:avatar_name});
};
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```